# Junior in VR. Google map, google streetview and RTSP

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr

I'm new comer to VR and I ask you for tips and link for quick start.

My goal is Application for Oculus Gear VR
Inside of App I need:
Show to user Google map (and markers on the map) - with option zoom in/out
On the click on button (or something else ) - Go to Google Streetview
And also I need to few boxes where I will show video from the cameras. I do it right now in the web with RTSP streaming.
Also additional questions:
Is VR app differ from simple game app in Unity (Like Android or Iphone game)

I will appreciated any links and help
(Sorry for my English grammar)
Thank you.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well what you are asking for.

> Is VR app differ from simple game app in Unity (Like Android or Iphone
>   game)?

It is in fact a simple game app in Unity using special plugind which manages the cameras and the input. But in fact a game made in Unity is portable to Oculus

Regards